# Python: Best way to check if all tuples in a list are empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have the following list:

```
In [572]: l2
Out[572]: [(), (), ()]
```

I need to check if all tuples within the list are empty.

**My attempt**:

```
In [581]: x = [True if i else False for i in l2]

In [584]: x
Out[584]: [False, False, False]

In [583]: not any(x)
Out[583]: True
```

I used a list comprehension to create a list with boolean values (`True`) if tuple is not empty, (`False`) if tuple is empty.

Then I'm using `any` to check if all elements is my list all `False`.

Is there a more concise way of doing all this?

Comment: `not any(l2)`...

Comment: @deceze How does `not any(l2)` work? In my understanding `any` will take an iterable and return `False` if all elements in iterable are `False`. How is `()` evaluated to `False` automatically?

Comment: It's *falsey*. The same way that `True if i else False` evaluates the value as truthy or falsey.

Comment: Tip: any variation of `True if ... else False` is basically always superfluous. The `...` itself is already truthy or falsey, otherwise the `if` wouldn't work at all. If you require to turn your arbitrary value into an actual boolean, use `bool(...)`.

Comment: If you actually need for some reason to get a `True` or `False` value explicitly, you can still do that more concisely: just use the `bool` built in (i.e, the type itself).

Answer (score 1):

@deceze has already provided a way which is probably the best with `not any(l2)`.

Here is another way using the generator expression:

```
l2 = [(), (), ()]
try:
    out = next(elt for elt in l2 if elt)
except StopIteration:
    print("all elements are empty")
```